# Creating a custom Transition that zooms into circle view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to create a custom iOS 7 Transition. At present I have a simple circle view like this:
[image]

I have a gesture recogniser on the custom view. When clicked the custom transition delegate is called

```
`-[CCZTTransitionDelegate animationControllerForPresentedController:presentingController:sourceController:]`
```

Which in turn calls the two methods on the transition animating class:

```
-[CCZTAnimatedTransitioning transitionDuration:]
-[CCZTAnimatedTransitioning animateTransition:]
```

At present I have just made the second controller zoom in and that is all working fine...

**Desired Effect**
What I would like to do when the circle is tapped is
1. have the circle increase in size until the screen is completed covered with its color.
2. Fade the second controller in

What is the best way to complete step 1? Can this be completed in the transition delegate/transition animating methods?

In this method `- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext` it looks like I have access to the view controllers but not the subview.  Should the animation be done before somehow if so how?

Note: In time there will eventually be a group of the circles not just one.

EDIT:
It is also important to note that I am actually trying to zoom in from the center of the circle. So if the circle is positioned elsewhere (i.e. when there are more) the circle should zoom in/increase in size from its own center point.

Comment: What type of object is the circle? I mean behind..is not an UIView?

Comment: maybe try using a CGAffineTransformScale on the circle and expand it to fill the entire view. Once it's filled the view, present your next view controller behind the filled view and then fade out the view, revealing your newly presented view controller

Comment: @MatteoGobbi - Yes type of UIView with layer radius change.

Comment: @croberth - How would I determine that the circle has filled the entire view though? For example if a circle is top right compared to bottom left etc. Also how would I fade out?

Comment: You can access the subview by adding a public property for the subview and accessing it via the view controller.

Comment: Then if I have 20 circles I would have a property for each which seems a bit much. I am attempting the suggested solution fro @croberth

Comment: you would use a uiview animation block with completion. So you'll know when the animation is complete by the completion block. Then fade the uiview you just made scaled up by changing it's alpha value, again inside of a uiview animation block

Comment: Let me understand...if the circle is not in the center but is in the top right for example..what effect do you want apply?

Comment: @MatteoGobbi - The same effect as if it is in the middle. I think I have sorted this with a CGAffineTransformScale as suggested. The only issue I currently have is the reverse, when the transition is reversed the circle view is no longer on the actual view controller?

Comment: @croberth - Please submit your suggested answer and I can submit another question for any other issues

Comment: so you want zoom in the center of the circle until when the violet part doesn't fill all the view? But you want so that for example is in the corner top left, the circle expands itself in right and down..right?

Comment: Seperate question created for different issue : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574403/custom-transition-causing-view-controller-view-to-be-in-an-incorrect-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CGAffineTransformScale animation on the circle view and expand it to fill the entire view. Once that is done scaling up (either through the UIView animation completion block or by using UIViewKeyFrameAnimation), present your next view controller behind the filled in view. Once presented, fade out the view to reveal the newly presented view controller by alpha-ing down the view in an animation block.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, eventually ;)